# Conditionally applying css not working in React JS using Typescript

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, conditional-statements

I have the following code whereas onclick I should make the Box stay highlighted with the black border.

```
interface BigButtonProps {


onClick(): void;
  Title: string;
  Description?: string;
  startIcon?: React.ElementType;
}

const BigButton: FC<BigButtonProps> = (props: BigButtonProps, { active }) => {
  const [isClicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
  const clickMe = () => {
    setClicked(!isClicked);
    console.log("say hello");
  };
  const SvgIconStyles: CSS.Properties = {
    display: "block",
  };
  const BoxStyles: CSS.Properties = {
    border: "1.5px solid black",
  };

  const BoxStylesActive: CSS.Properties = {
    border: "1.5px solid black",
  };
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        height: {
          xs: "45px",
          md: "100px",
        },
        width: {
          xs: "45px",
          md: "300px",
        },
    borderRadius: "10px",

    boxShadow: "0 2px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)",
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    flexDirection: "column",
    ":hover": {
      border: "1.5px solid blue",
    },
  }}
  className={classNames("BoxStyles", { BoxStylesActive: isClicked })}
  onClick={() => {
    clickMe();
  }}
>
  <Typography variant="h1">{props.Title}</Typography>

  <Typography variant="subtitle1">{props.Description}</Typography>
  <SvgIcon
    component={CheckCircleIcon}
    sx={{
      display: "block",
    }}
  />
</Box>


);
};

export default BigButton;
```

When I click on the button it should change the border color to solid black. When I do CSS active it does change on click but doesn't remain changed to black. So I have to apply CSS conditionally so I did create the CSS methods with the property type CSS.Properties; I'm using typescript and this is a react component I'm working on with. I'm not really sure what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hmm I don't see how that'd apply the styles that are in local variables. `BoxStyles` and `BoxStylesActive` are just local variables and are not actual classes.

Comment: This question is badly written. You should provide a minimal code example where you cut out unneeded information. Also, please provide used libraries next time like `sx` or `classNames()`. I know those, because I worked in the past with those, but many people don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like

```
<Box styles={isClicked ? BoxStylesActive : BoxStyles}>
// ...
```

Notice that `BoxStylesActive` and `BoxStyles` are the same in your pasted code. So don't be surprised if you see no changes.

```
<Box sx={{border: isClicked ? "1.5px solid black" : none}}>
// ...
```

This can be used alternatively.

You are mixing sx prop and styles here. Also your `BoxStylesActive` is an object and no css class. So using `classNames()` won't have an effect on it.